# Azure SDK v2 - unable to download job output using mlclient

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I was using functionality from last few months, but recently started facing some issue with the below code. I'm running the code using JupyterLab and unable to download the predictions result. However, The batch endpoint is getting invoked and able to stream the job. Additionally, I can see the prediction output saved in Azure Blob Storage.

I'm also not getting any error message.

```
# invoke the endpoint for batch scoring job
print("Invoking the Batch Endpoint...")
job = ml_client.batch_endpoints.invoke(
    endpoint_name=batch_endpoint_name,
    input=score_dataset_input,                    
    deployment_name=batch_deployment_name,     
    params_override=[
        {"mini_batch_size": str(mini_batch_size)}, 
        {"compute.instance_count": str(compute_instance_count)},
        {"output_file_name": f"{prediction_output_file_name}.csv"}
     ]           
)
print("Batch Endpoint invoked with the provided payload....")

print("Streaming the Job...")
job_name = job.name
batch_job_stream = ml_client.jobs.stream(name=job_name)

# download the job logs and output
ml_client.jobs.download(batch_job.name, 
                        download_path= f"{batch_prediction_dir}/csv/", 
                        output_name="predictions")
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever, we invoke batch-endpopint, it will create a new job and save the prediction output at path `f"container_name/{job-run-id}/score"` in workspace default storage.

Below is the code, I'm currently using to fetch the prediction output.Thanks @ooxvyd, for suggesting alternate approach:)

````
job_name = job.name
batch_job = ml_client.jobs.get(name=job_name)
print(f"Job Name: {job_name}")

# stream the job logs
ml_client.jobs.stream(name=job_name)
print("Prediction complete")

# Get final batch processing Job <run id>
for job in ml_client.jobs.list(parent_job_name=job_name):
    final_job_run_id = job.name
print(f"Final Job Run Id: {final_job_run_id}")

blob_storage = ws.get_default_datastore()
prediction_output_path = f"azureml/{final_job_run_id}/score/predictions.csv"

blob_storage.download(target_path="./", prefix=prediction_output_path, overwrite=True, show_progress=False)
pred_data = pd.read_csv(prediction_output_path, delimiter= " ", names=["hash", "y_preds"])```
````